# WHERE statement not working with numbers and dates (SQLite)

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a problem in the program of DBlite (a rubbish program I have to use for college) with dates and numbers in the where section. My code is shown below:

```
SELECT Customers_Details_FULL_LOCKED.email
FROM Customers_Details_FULL_LOCKED
LEFT JOIN Purchases_FULL_LOCKED ON Customers_Details_FULL_LOCKED.customer_id 
= Purchases_FULL_LOCKED.Cust_ID
WHERE Purchases_FULL_LOCKED.Purchase_Price = '>20' AND 
Customers_Details_FULL_LOCKED.marketing_opt_in = 'Yes' AND 
Purchases_FULL_LOCKED.Purchase_Date = '<2014-01-01';
```

Objectives:
I want my code to show the email of those who have made a purchase of over 20, they have opted into marketing and the purchase date is before 2014.

What I know:

I know that the opt_in statement is working, but the purchase price and purchase date are both not working, singularly or together.

I also know that for the purchase price it doesn't matter whether it is CAST as a decimal or not, still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Well, SQLIite doesn't really have a `date` data type to begin with. But `= '>20'`  means "where the column contains a value that contains the string `>20`". I guess you meant to write `>= 20` instead

Comment: you can't put a `<` inside a string and have the query read it as a number or date. If you mean less/greater than or equal then write `Purchase_Price >= 20` (or `Purchase_Date <= '2014-01-01'`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks! I was being a complete noob with the operators, thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

If Purchase_Price is a number value, you should compare the column with an operator `<, >, >= ..` and a number value.

Write `Purchase_Price > 20` instead of `Purchase_Price = '>20'`
Here it tells: *Purchase_Price must be greater than 20*.
 Instead of *Purchase_Price is equal to the text '>20'*

Same thing with the date, but you should compare date value